# Can't post list of objects, also only limited number of response headers are allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I apologize, i'm a bit new to Angular (as well as the ASP.net environment as a whole). I've created a list of customers that are retrieved from an API .net service. I then put checkboxes next to each of them indicating if they are active or inactive customers. The idea is that when you scroll through the list, you can check these boxes, press 'save' and it will update the database on which customers are active or not. Here's what my attempt looks like:

```
app.controller("CustomersController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(serviceURL + "/customers")
    .then(function onSuccess(response) {
        $scope.customers = response.data;
    }, function onError(response) {
        //~
    });

    $scope.saveCustomers = function () {
        $http.post(serviceURL + "/customers", $scope.customers)
        .then(function onSuccess(response) {
            //~
        }, function onError(response) {
            //~
        });

    };
});
```

Here, saveCustomers is called from the save button being pressed in the HTML file, with the checkmark values altered within the scope. When I post this, I get a 400 HTTP response (even though the list of objects it returns looks good in the console). I even tried to JSONconvert out of chance. Then I iterated and tried to do a post in a loop for each object in $scope.customers. However, this returned a 409 HTTP response instead, and i'm not exactly sure what this implies for my post. I have tried PUT, but it is not allowed in the headers. I've attempted to fix this by adding this to the Web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    ....
```

As well as altering the Handler Mappings in IIS manager so that ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 includes the verbs PUT and DELETE. 
I have an "Add customer" page that uses a post for a single object on a form, and it works perfectly. I've spent a few hours trying everything I possible could, but I can't get this simple thing to work. Also, here is my HTML for reference:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in customers | filter:txtFilter">
   <td>
      {{a.customer_id}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{a.customer_name}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{a.customer_phone}}
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox"
            name="selectedInactives[]"
            value="{{a.inactive}}"
            ng-checked="a.inactive"
            ng-click="toggleSelection(a.inactive)" 
            ng-true-value="{{1}}" 
            ng-false-value="{{0}}"
            /> {{a.inactive}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

(Note: don't worry about ng-true-value or false value being set to the integer values, it doesn't make a difference)

Comment: If you want two-way binding with the checkbox, the code should use `ng-model`, only use `ng-checked` for one-way binding. Do not use `ng-checked` and `ng-model` together on the same checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I'm a little confused with it because my database has values "1/0" but when http get is called, it converts them all to "true" and "false". I don't imagine sending them back to the server in that format would cause problems, but I tried playing with it to see.

Comment: Right now the code sets `ng-value-true/false` to string values. Did you try posting number values?

Comment: I did try with a single post on the first record which changes to a value when I select it, but I can't seem to get the entire set of rows to have 1s or 0s by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 $http.post(serviceURL + "/customers",{customrers: $scope.customers}).then();
```

Instead of 'customrers:' put the prop name in your backend function.

Comment: By the prop name are you referring to the parameter for the post method? If so that one is just customer, which in my case the backend throws a DBentityvalidation exception (which I configured to show that the "customer_id field is required). Using the prop name of customer_id doesn't seem to achieve anything either, throwing a 400 bad request if left with $scope.customers or a 409 error if running this in a loop where '$scope.customers' is replaced with 'selected.customer_id'

Answer (score 0):

Don't use interpolation (`{{ }}`) with the `ng-*-value` directives. Interpolation with double curly brackets converts AngularJS expressions to strings.

To use numeric values:

```
 <input type="checkbox"
        name="selectedInactives[]"
        ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶a̶.̶i̶n̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶}̶}̶"̶
        ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶=̶"̶a̶.̶i̶n̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶"̶
        ng-model="a.inactive"
        ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶t̶o̶g̶g̶l̶e̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶a̶.̶i̶n̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶)̶"̶ ̶
        ng-change="toggleSelection(a)" 
        ̶n̶g̶-̶t̶r̶u̶e̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶1̶}̶}̶"̶ ̶
        ng-true-value="1" 
        ̶n̶g̶-̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶-̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶0̶}̶}̶"̶
        ng-false-value="0"
        /> {{a.inactive}}
```